# How do I get a Text Area in Netbeans to display content that I already have saved in a Text File?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

How do I get a Text Area in Netbeans to display content that I already have saved in a Text File? I want the text area txtAllOrders to display the content that I have in a text file Output.txt when I click on the button btnViewOrders.

Comment: You  actually need to write a code for that , and if you have already written it then do Post it too !!!

Comment: you asked before the question how to get text from the area to a file did it work? I ask because you either accept an answer or wirte a comment that you have it working

Comment: yes the previous one worked...thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro programmer in Java so pls correct me if I'm wrong, but I would try this:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("YourFile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String sw ="";
try
{
     while(sw != null)
     {
         sw = br.readLine();
         txtAllOrders.append(sw + "\n");
     }
} catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You answer is good , but please don't do **Homework** , As this site is not for that purpose !!!!

Comment: @NeerajJain you're right sry I remember next time and delete my answer or should I leave it for others to be helpful?

Comment: No need to delete Upvoted already  !! **Help in a way that actually helps , Avoid spoon feeding**

Comment: ok sry I remember and sry again, I'm active member since a few weeks ;) I will watch my steps now better

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the following code to the click event of your `btnViewOrders`

```java
    File file = new File("Output.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    String text = "";

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        int content;
        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
            text += (char) content;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    txtAllOrders.setText(text);
```